# Android Firebase query with LimitToFast getting error Can't call limitToLast on query with previously set limit

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I am trying to paginate the chat lists of users. Before pagination, the query was working fine. But as soon as I have tried Pagination, I get an error of:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't call limitToLast on query with a previously set limit!
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.limitToFirst(Query.java:559)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.paging.FirebaseDataSource.loadInitial(FirebaseDataSource.java:71)
        at androidx.paging.PageKeyedDataSource.dispatchLoadInitial(PageKeyedDataSource.java:339)
        at androidx.paging.ContiguousPagedList.<init>(ContiguousPagedList.java:175)
        at androidx.paging.PagedList.create(PagedList.java:216)
        at androidx.paging.PagedList$Builder.build(PagedList.java:388)
        at androidx.paging.LivePagedListBuilder$1.compute(LivePagedListBuilder.java:206)
        at androidx.paging.LivePagedListBuilder$1.compute(LivePagedListBuilder.java:171)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(ComputableLiveData.java:101)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source:6)
```

My Query, Config, Options code:

```
 PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                    .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                    .setPrefetchDistance(5)
                    .setPageSize(10)
                    .build();
            Query mQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Message").child(roomId).orderByChild("timestamp").limitToFirst(20);
            DatabasePagingOptions<Message> options = new DatabasePagingOptions.Builder<Message>()
                    .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                    .setQuery(mQuery, config, Message.class)
                    .build();
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling somehow `.limitToFirst(20)` twice?

Comment: no brother.  this is my Query : Query mQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Message").child(roomId).orderByChild("timestamp").limitToFirst(20);